# Debian - InitScript - "Do NOT set -e" in /etc/init.d/skeleton

Tags: bash, debian, init.d, lsb

I was wondering why "Do NOT set -e" was present in /etc/init.d/skeleton as I thought it was always good practice.

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          skeleton
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Example initscript
# Description:       This file should be used to construct scripts to be
#                    placed in /etc/init.d.
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Foo Bar <foobar@baz.org>
#
# Please remove the "Author" lines above and replace them
# with your own name if you copy and modify this script.

# Do NOT "set -e"
```

Debian wiki recommends it (https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/StatusSupport) so I don't know what I should do.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/a/416097/356862

Comment: Also see [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I'll drop set -e from now on then.